# БЭМ - позиционирование и отступы через модификатор

Tags: бэм

Можно ли так делать в данной методологии -

При условии что в title_offset будет отступ вниз?

```html
    <h1 class="title title_offset">Заголовок</h1>
```

Comment: Можно. В документации описано, что изменить блок можно с помощью модификатора, микса, контекста. В Вашем случае можно дать отступ используя модификтор `title_offset`